# How To Timeout PRAW Stream When A Search Not Successfull

Tags: python-3.x, timeout, bots, reddit, praw

I just begin to use PRAW and fascinating with it.

I am trying to search **r/all** for a matching submission title.
If the search successfull my code will proceed and break in the first match, and then the script will restart by a cronjob with a new matching string.

When my bot trying to search and match submission title, if there's still no match the script won't stop and keep searching for whole day for that given string.

Is there any way to limit the searching time Or timeout the stream?

Trying to browse PRAW docs for hours but still no luck.

Here is my code

```
import matching_string

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("all")

for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():       

    if matching_string in submission.title:

        process_submission(submission)

        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `limit` parameter in `.submissions()`

```
for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions(limit=anyInt):
```

Comment: That is not a timeout. But limit the posts search itself. However I have got the solution from some forum on reddit. Thanks for reply.